# Hide number of sections and chapters in iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I need to hide the number of sections and chapters within the files that I generate with iTextSharp (within the content of the file, I do not care about bookmarks), for example I would need to change the actual result generated this way:

1. This is Chapter Title 1

   1.1. This in section Title 1

by the following:

This is Chapter Title 1

This in section Title 1

I tried the following code, overriding the method OnSection:

```
public override void OnSection(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition, int depth, Paragraph title)

    {title.RemoveAt(0);
        base.OnSection(writer, document, paragraphPosition, depth, title);
    }
```

But I did not get any results, could anyone help?
Thank you very much,
Ariel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [chapter](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chapter.html) number has to be created using a Paragraph as title and an int as chapter number. The chapter number is shown by default. If you don't want to see the chapter number, you have to set the `numberdepth` to 0.

The same counts for [section](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Section.html#Section%28com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph,%20int%29).

Sample:

```
Chapter chapter = new Chapter("ChapterTitle", 0);
chapter.NumberDepth = 0;

Section section = chapter.AddSection("Title", 0);
```